# razor engine template parse without specific type

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

Is there a way to `RunCompile()` a Razor Engine template without declaring  `typeof(someType)` ?

I want to avoid having multiple methods like these:

```
    public static string EvalueateLineChartModelTemplate(d3LineCharts.LineChartModel model, string cssResourceName, string tempKey)
    {
        string template = StreamEmbeddedResource(cssResourceName);
        string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, tempKey, typeof(d3LineCharts.LineChartModel), model);
        return result;
    }

    public static string EvalueateAreaChartModelTemplate(d3AreaCharts.AreaChartModel model, string cssResourceName, string tempKey)
    {
        string template = StreamEmbeddedResource(cssResourceName);
        string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, tempKey, typeof(d3AreaCharts.AreaChartModel), model);
        return result;
    }
```

How can I combine these two methods into a single more generic method so that I can still call it with different types? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a generic method like this:

```
public static string EvaluateTemplate<T>(T model, string cssResourceName, string tempKey)
{
    string template = StreamEmbeddedResource(cssResourceName);
    string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, tempKey, typeof(T), model);
    return result;
}
```

You can then call the generic method just like you would for your type-specific versions:

```
d3LineCharts.LineChartModel lineChartModel = new d3LineCharts.LineChartModel();
string result = EvaluateTemplate(lineChartModel, cssResourceName, tempKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public static string EvalueateChartModelTemplate<T>(T model, string cssResourceName, string tempKey)
{
    string template = StreamEmbeddedResource(cssResourceName);
    string result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, tempKey, typeof(T), model);
    return result;
}
```

Your calls would then look like:

```
var result1 = EvalueateChartModelTemplate<d3LineCharts.LineChartModel>(lineChartModel, lineChartResourceName, lineChartKey);
var result2 = EvalueateChartModelTemplate<d3LineCharts.AreaChartModel>(areaChartModel, areaChartResourceName, areaChartKey);
```

I left the generic parameter in the method calls (the `<d3XXXCharts.XXXChartModel>` part) just to make it clear to you what is going on, but that is of course redundant because the compiler can infer that from the model parameter of the method call.